# OpenGL and Direct3D

Tags: opengl, directx

What is the difference between OpenGL and Direct3D? Are they truly different implementations to accomplish the same things (like Java and Mirosoft's CLR [.NET])?

Comment: DirectX is more than just 3D graphics don't you mean Direct3D vs OpenGL?

Comment: Your right, I fixed it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are very different graphics API's.  But it's fair to say they mostly accomplish the same thing.  DirectX is probably the API of choice if you are developing a game under windows (or a game for XBOX), and OpenGL is the choice if you want cross-platform support.  Mac OS uses GL, as does the iPhone, for example, and many windows games also support OpenGL.

Because OpenGL was developed over a long time and 'by committee', it comes with a lot of baggage - the API has some older options that aren't really relevant today.  That's one of the reasons for OpenGL ES; it cuts out all the junk and makes for an easier target platform.

DirectX on the other hand is controlled by Microsoft, and as such it has a more 'modern' feel to it (it's based on COM components, so is highly object oriented).  MS often update the API to match new hardware.

Sometimes you don't have the luxury of choice (iphone for example can't run DX).  But often it just comes down to personal preference/experience.  If your a long-time graphics programmer, you tend to get pretty familiar with both...

Update:
Since I wrote this the landscape has changed a lot.  These days on Mac you are encouraged to use Metal, although there is the option to use Vulkan and the 'Molten' compatibility layer.
We also have Vulkan and DX12.  These are 'to the metal' APIs which are hugely complicated to learn but give you complete control.  Personally, I'd still recommend learning OpenGL first, then move onto DX12/Vulkan/Molten if you need the control or have no choice.  The best current 'cross platform' solution is Vulkan.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. that gives me a very clear picture of the two.

Answer (score 3):

Google is your friend in this case...there's a good Wikipedia article contrastring the two libraries:

[Comparison of OpenGL and Direct3D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_OpenGL_and_Direct3D)

If memory serves, OpenGL was the open implementation before Direct3D came out. Direct3D was then based off of OpenGL...but quickly diverged and became it's own distinct library.

**UPDATE**

Looks like my memory is shot...

Direct3D was developed independtly of OpenGL.

Comment: Direct3D wasn't based off of OGL (though they both used the same basic model for rendering.)  The history of D3D before 5.0 is definitely weird (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct3D#History).

Comment: Heh - I worked on Direct3D before it became Direct3D ;-) Definitely not based on OpenGL...

Answer (score 3):

Direct3D and OpenGL are different API's used to accomplish the same thing.

The major differences between D3D and GL is that D3D is Object Oriented and GL is not.
D3D9 and GLES2 basically have the same features. In fact if you plan on using OpenGL and do not need any GL3 or GL4 features you should base all you code on the GLES2 API(all GLES2 features are in GL2, but not the other way around).

If possible you should always use D3D over GL on windows, as multithreading and driver support is flaky. Take the netbooks for example, they support D3D's HLSL at ShaderModel 2 but don't support the equivalent for GLSL, they only support a fixed pipeline for GL.